# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x58)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy tratando de reproducir algunos archivos de sonido con botones pero al pulsar el boton me arroja este error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x58) en la linea

```
audioPlayer.play()
```

eh buscado posibles soluciones y no encuentro nada relacionado con ese error, la funcion de mi codigo se ejecuta bien hasta el print, este es mi codigo completo.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var track: String? = nil
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func heavyButton(_ sender: Any) {
        track = "H"
        print("heavy machine gun \(track!)")
        reproducirAudio(audio: track!)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

func reproducirAudio(audio: String) {
        do {
            print("entro a la funcion de reproducir")
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: audio, ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu función de reproducir audio debería retornar algún tipo de valor boleano. Como sabes si se capturó en u error en el catch o no de esa función si en la llamada no hay ningún tipo de control para determinar si hay un error o no el recurso que le pasas puede ser mil o no y si es mil crashea la app porque no hay nada que reproducir debería poner un control sobre eso tipo if reproducir audio{ audiplayer.play()}

Answer (score 0):

a mí me pasó que ese código me funcionó hasta que actualicé a iOS 13.
Con iOS 13 me daba ese fallo.
Prueba esto:

```
 var player: AVAudioPlayer!

  //en el viewDidLoad:  
   if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "nombreSonido", withExtension:"wav"){
         do {
             player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
              } 
         catch {
                print(error)
               }
         player.prepareToPlay()
        }


//crea una función.  
    func reproducirSonido(sonido: AVAudioPlayer){
        if sonido.isPlaying {
            sonido.stop()
            sonido.play()
        }
        else{
            sonido.play()
        }
    }


  //en la función o funciones que necesites reproducir el sonido: 
  reproducirSonido(sonido: player)
```

espero que te sirva.

Comment: de hecho encontre la solusion para iOS 13 y algo importante es revisar los archivos de audio porque en algunas ocaciones por alguna razón xcode no los identifica https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473383/how-to-fix-thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x58-xcode/58506321#58506321